# prevent default is not working for me

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I've looked at many similiar examples on stackoverflow and other websites, but I can't seem to figure out why my preventdefault() is not working.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  $(function() {
    $('.cshero-team-carousel-item-wrap a').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log('hit');
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="cshero-team-title-wrap">
  <h3 class="cshero-team-title">
                <a style="color:#005780;" title="world" href="http://google.com" rel="">world</a>
            </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7z98w6eq/. What errors do you get?

Comment: @j08691 If you run the code in the question, you'll see `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @JuanMendes - Yes, the OP didn't include jQuery in his example. That's either because they're unfamiliar with stack snippets and didn't know how to, or actually left it out in their real code. Either way, the actual jQuery works, so I'm voting to close the question as off-topic due to a typo. Either that or it's a duplicate of dozens of other SO questions about not including jQuery.

Comment: Is your code in a document ready handler or at the end of the document?

Comment: @j08691 From the OP's comment on my answer, it looks like they are getting an empty jQuery object, so they probably need to wait for the `load` event

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `jQuery`. It's working if you include it and you make sure to run the code after the HTML has loaded. Your console should say:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cshero-team-title a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('hit');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cshero-team-title-wrap">
  <h3 class="cshero-team-title">
    <a style="color:#005780;" title="World" href="http://google.com" rel="">World</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Alternatively, [you can use delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which will listen on the body element (which is always available) but ignores clicks unless the event target matches the selector passed in.

```js
$(document.body).click('.cshero-team-title a', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('hit');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cshero-team-title-wrap">
  <h3 class="cshero-team-title">
    <a style="color:#005780;" title="World" href="http://google.com" rel="">World</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

You should always do some debugging before posting a question. That includes:

- Check console for errors
- Add breakpoints in your code and watch it run

Comment: I added jQuery in another part of the page it's just not shown here. So it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are probably running `$('.cshero-team-title a')` before the HTML is loaded, so `$('.cshero-team-title a')` is returning an empty set and not setting a handler on any elements. You can test that by adding `console.log($('.cshero-team-title a').length)`, if it's zero, it's because it's running before the HTML is available, add the code in a load handler: `$(function() { /* register handler here*/  })`

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your event handler in a document ready function? if not the click event is not being added to the link because the link doesn't exist when the javascript code is run.

```
$(function(){
    $('.cshero-team-title a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('hit');
    });
});
```

Comment: See my answer for an alternative that doesn't have to wait for the ready handler using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)